# Retrofit2 post JSON with field name

Tags: android, retrofit

Trying to POST something like this with GSON and retrofit:

```
{user: {"email":"asdfghj@wedssd.jk","name":"fjnhfioewhifhjierj","password":"password""} }
```

instead of

```
{"email":"asdfghj@wedssd.jk","name":"fjnhfioewhifhjierj","password":"password"}
```

TypedInput and TypedByteArray removed in 2.0, how this is possible?

Comment: You can maker JsonObject and convert it to String and return your String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create class with name User with variables email,name,password.
2. Create a Class with any name xyz having Object of User.

After that Parse xyz class for Gson with Retrofit.